# Doctrine 2 - Same Entity Multiple Join

Tags: php, join, doctrine-orm

I'm newbie in doctrine. I've got two tables messages and users. User entity have two joins, fromMessages and toMessages. Message entity have two joins, fromUser and toUser. My annotation is as follows:

User Entity:

```
/**
* @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $property
* @OneToMany(targetEntity="Message", mappedBy="fromUser", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
*/
protected $fromMessages;

/**
* @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $property
* @OneToMany(targetEntity="Message", mappedBy="toUser", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
*/
protected $toMessages;
```

Message Entity:

```
/**
 * @var User
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="fromMessages")
 * @JoinColumns({
 *  @JoinColumn(name="fromUserId", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
protected $fromUser;

/**
 * @var User
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="toMessages")
 * @JoinColumns({
 *  @JoinColumn(name="toUserId", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
protected $toUser;
```

I'm persist a message and after read messages with DQL("select u FROM App\Entities\User u") fromMessages is work but toMessages always return null. How can fix this problem?

Sorry my bad english. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting the value of toMessages on the 'owning' side of the relationship? (That is, the **many** side of the @OneToMany ?  As per the Doctrine 2 docs, only the owning side is persisted - the inverse side is discarded/ignored.